# Response Header Issue

Tags: html, css

I have this code and I want the css code with a `max-width: 780px`, the `.second` in a line alone because it is the logo, and the `.first` and `.third` on the line below. I don't know how to do it.

Normally, this elements are Ordered in one line with a wider width than `780px`. The normal order: `first, second, third`
The order I want with a `max-width: 780px`:

.................second..............

........first........|.......third......

```
<header>
      <div class="first">
      </div>
      <div class="second">
      </div>
      <div class="third">
      </div>
</header>
```

```css
header {
  background: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
}
.SearchBar {
  width: 30%;
  height: 130px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
.SearchBar:before {
  /* create a full-height inline block pseudo=element */
  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
  height: 100%;
}
.SearchBar>p {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
.SearchBar>p>input {
  background: url("../images/search_icon.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  background-position: 90% 50%;
  width: 230px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
  font-family: FuturaLight;
  text-indent: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.SearchBar>p>input:enabled {
  cursor: text;
}
.logo {
  width: 40%;
  height: 130px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.logo:before {
  /* create a full-height inline block pseudo=element */
  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
  height: 100%;
}
.logo a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
}
.shoppingcar {
  width: 30%;
  height: 130px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}
.shoppingcar:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
.cartletter {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: FuturaLight;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="subheader"></div>
  <div class="SearchBar">
    <a> FIRST</a>
  </div>
  <div class="logo">
    <a> SECOND</a>
  </div>
  <div class="shoppingcar">
    <p class="cartletter">
      <a> THIRD</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Why you don't change html? Maybe, second box needs to be the first box.

Comment: Make sure you provide [either a Fiddle or a CSS sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help people answering your question!

Comment: if I put the second box first it doesn't work... the second box is the logo... and I need this box alone in the first line with this width

Comment: @KennyAmaro if you change the position of the second box to be the first box (don't need to change class names), only with a `.second { display: block; }` it works, no need to write more css, and don't do rarely tricks to put above the box of below, it's strange and poor. If you can change the html, is best than this.

Comment: lol it works changing the position, thanks @MarcosPérezGude

Comment: Obviously, html works like we read, left to right, up to down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm, well since there's no `css` code and `jsfiddle`, I'm assuming  this can do the trick ? try it on and let me know please ?

```
@media all and (max-width: 780px) {
    .second  { 
      display:inline-block;
     }
    .first {
     display:inline;
     float:left;
     }
    .third {
     display:inline;
     float:right;
     }
}
```